# Git workflow for building on top of someonelses codebase

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

I am needing to interface with other developers on a web application project. It was recommended by others I look into using git.

Most of our work on project rely on codebase maintained by others that we have a license to. Our work is mainly re branding that code and adding or removing features as needed (this is done to simplify client documentation and user interactions). What git workflow would be best to allow us to integrate the original codebase maintainers work into our code? We would never submit anything back to the codebase maintainer. All the code is php, html, css, js...

I am quite new to using Git and have never used it on a project before. I have gone through most of Atlassian tutorials but am a bit lost on how to apply it to my current needs. I am currently using bitbucket with sourcetree (but I do have Gitbash and TortoiseGit installed)

I tried searching the question, but I'm a little too new to Git to apparently even to know what terms to search for. I found the following thread that seem to touch on this subject but I don't think they are what I am looking for:
[Proper Git workflow for combined OS and Private code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195826/proper-git-workflow-for-combined-os-and-private-code)

My guess is that I need to setup a master branch, then off this a new branch called basesource. Then update the master off basesource, then branch and create a development branch. do my work off the development branch. Then when I receive updated to the basesource add the changes to the basesource and pull those into the master and then pull those into the development branch? Then do any releases off the development branch and not the master?

Or is this just stupid and should I just use some mutlifile diff to see what changed in the source and manually make changes to our version?

Comment: Why did someone down rank this question? I spent nearly a day researching and trying to find the answer. That was after reading the material on how to use Git and Git workflows. Not everyone is so familiar with new terms so what may seem obvious to one person is not so to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to version the modifications that you will be making to the third-party dependency, you might want to give Git [submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) a read, since it appears relatively appropriate for your situation.

Submodules allow you to keep commits made to your project and the code base for the third-party dependency (i.e. in a subdirectory of your main project repository) seperate, while everything is under one common repository.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be what I was asking for. The implementation looks to be very difficult and way above my current ability level. Do you or anyone else know a simpler way?

Comment: Just to add since I noted I am using source tree for others here is a blog on this subject http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/02/01/using-submodules-and-subrepositories/