# How to integrate a pull request to a subproject into a subdirectory of a main project?

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I am contemplating a git repository structure with a mix of open and closed source software. The current situation is somewhat of a hodgepodge. Multiple developers are working on the project, geographically distributed. The authorative repository is on a private *GitLab* server.

The directory structure would be something like this:

```
repo
|-- core (open source)
|-- moduleA (open source)
|-- moduleB (open source)
|-- moduleC (closed source)
```

In reality there are a lot more modules, but anyway.

I have evaluated **submodules** as well as **subtrees**, and they do not fit our development process. I found this related question, but the answers there do not satisfy me either: [Proper Git workflow for combined OS and Private code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195826/proper-git-workflow-for-combined-os-and-private-code)

Separate repos is the current situation, as it was before a migration from svn, and we're not satisfied with that either.

What I see as a workable solution, is one big repo, and have a Jenkins job that runs `git subtree split` to split out the open source modules into separate repos, and then push those to the outside world, on *GitHub*. This would be the easiest way to work for the development team, and would only require a one time setup in Jenkins. I found a step-by-step description in [Detach (move) subdirectory into separate Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository/17864475#17864475).

But now come my actual **questions**.

When the Open Source code is on *GitHub*, we will get pull requests from outside contributors. Their patches will be to the *root* of a repository, while in the authorative private repository in *GitLab*, and also on the developers' workstations, the changes should apply to a *subdirectory*.

1. How do I integrate a pull request for a root to a subdirectory?
2. When the code is integrated, and Jenkins splits off the code between Open Source and private, will *GitHub* pick up that the pull request is merged and automatically close it? I think I can reduce that question to: what does GitHub use to close a pull request? I think it *should* be safe, provided that the answer to question 1 provides something that is reversible.

EDIT: I'm thinking about a slightly different flow:

1. `git subtree split` to split out the open source modules into separate repos.
2. `git subtree` to recombine the open source modules into a new repository.
3. Push that new repository to GitHub.

This has the following advantages:

- Directory structure of the internal GitLab repo and the external GitHub repo is identical (except of course for the closed source stuff)
- Only one repo needs to be published to the outside world.
- I will be able to merge pull requests with `git cherry-pick`.

Disadvantages:

- It's a bit of a convoluted setup.
- Pull requests will still not be closed automatically, probably.